# Xamarin iOS: Images are not available on Storyboard

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

For my xamarin iOS project, I added few images in resource folder and marked them as bundle resource. I went to the storyboard and tried to pull those images from button's background image property but I am not able to view them there. I can set them manually but not able to see/set them via storyboard.

I rebuild the app still no effect. Any advise? Am i missing anything ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add it as an Image Set in `Assets.xcassets` here:

[image]

Then it will show in the storyboard:

[image]